# error resolution for androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-activity

I tried to create an aar in AndroidStudio and connect it in Unity, but I got an error on the actual device.
I think I should add androidx.activity.ComponentActivity, but I'm not sure which file to add.
Can you please help me?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity;
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

※The code that is throwing up the error

◇MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.biometricslibs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static MainActivity instance() {
        return new MainActivity();
    }

    private Executor executor = new MainThreadExecutor();
    private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;

    private BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback callback = new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            if (errorCode == 13 && biometricPrompt != null)
                biometricPrompt.cancelAuthentication();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
        }
    };

    public void BiometricCheck(Context context) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt((AppCompatActivity) context, executor, callback);

        BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("title")
                .setSubtitle("subTitle")
                .setDescription("description")
                .setNegativeButtonText("cancel")
                .build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
    }
}
```

◇MainThreadExecutor.java

```
package com.example.biometricslibs;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        handler.post(r);
    }
}
```

◇UnityC#

```
using(var nativeDialog = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.biometricslibs.MainActivity"))
        {
            using(var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                using(var currentUnityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                {
                    using(var instance = nativeDialog.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance"))
                    {
                        instance.Call(
                            "BiometricCheck",
                            currentUnityActivity
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post the full error stack trace.

Comment: @Vaibhav Goyal  Here is the corresponding code

Comment: Extend the Main Activity with Activity class. Like this public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: I see! I'll check it out right away.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal 　I tested it. I'm still having trouble with the new error. Can you please help me?
The error description and code have been updated.